# Removing Item from DOM display (React)

Tags: reactjs

[sample image of page so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCa4T.png)

Please see the above image.  I'm wanting to be able to remove the string in the "skill" column when it is deleted after clicking the "Delete" button on the right. I can delete an Employee using filter() with the Delete button on the left. This removes the entire row from the DOM, which is great, but I would like the Delete button on the right to simply remove the content from the Skill(s) column for that particular employee.

I have tried doing something similar in the deleteSkill() function, but I am not sure how to remove the content of the Skill(s) column without deleting the entire row. The issue lies in my setList() function within my deleteSkill() function. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const List = () => {

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  //DELETE Employee by ID
  const deleteEmployee = async (id) => {
    try {
      const deleteEmployee = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/employees/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE"
      });

      setList(list.filter(item => item.employee_uuid !== id));

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  };

  //DELETE Skill by ID
  const deleteSkill = async (id) => {
    try {
      const deleteSkill = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/employees/${id}/skills`, {
        method: "DELETE"
      });

      setList(list.filter(item => item.summary !== id));

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  };

  const getList = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/employees")
      const jsonData = await response.json();

      setList(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getList();
  }, []);

  console.log(list);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {" "}
      <h1 class="text-center">Employee Skills Tracker</h1>
      <table class="table mt-5 text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Skill(s)</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {list.map(item => (
            <tr key={item.employee_uuid}>
              <td>{item.firstname}</td>
              <td>{item.lastname}</td>
              <td>Edit</td>
              <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteEmployee(item.employee_uuid)}>Delete</button></td>
              <td>{item.summary}</td>
              <td>Edit</td>
              <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteSkill(item.employee_uuid)} >Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `list.filter()`, use `list.map()`. The key is that you want to return a 1:1 list of modified elements, not a list without certain elements.

If you want to remove the summary for just a specific employee, I'd recommend

```js
setList(list.map(item => {
    if (item.id !== id) {
      return item; // not the right employee, pass it through
    }
    let newItem = {...item};
    delete newItem.summary;
    return newItem;
}));
```

It's more complex, because you have to explicitly return what you want, but it's also what you're asking for.

Comment: Glad to help! :-)